# ¿Cómo puedo declarar una tupla nominada con "parámetros ilimitados"?

Tags: python-3.x, tuplas, collection

```
from collections import namedtuple
import datetime
import csv

TuplaN = namedtuple("TuplaN", ("Nombre", "Fecha", "DescripcionServicio",
                            "DescripcionEquipo", "MontoPorEquipo", "MontoTotal"))

Diccionario={}
#Lista = []
Separador="*"*20

print()
print("BIENVENIDO...REGISTRA Y CONSULTA SERVICIOS AQUI")
print()

while True:
    print("MENÚ".center(44,"*"))
    print("\t1) Registrar servicio")  # Registrar servicio
    print("\t2) Salir y guardar en CSV")

    Respuesta = int(input("Elija una opción: "))

    if Respuesta == 1:
        Lista = []
        Mi_TuplaN=()
        print()
        print(Separador,"REGISTRA AQUI TU SERVICIO",Separador)

        while True:
            if Diccionario.keys():
                Clave = max(Diccionario.keys())+1
            else:
                Clave = 1
            Diccionario[Clave] = Mi_TuplaN
            break


        NombreCliente=str(input("Digita el nombre del cliente: "))
        while True:
            try:
                FechaCapturada = input('Digite la fecha inicio (DD/MM/AAAA)): ')
                Fecha =datetime.datetime.strptime(FechaCapturada, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
                Lista.append(NombreCliente)
                Lista.append(Fecha)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('ERROR: Debe digitar una fecha valida con el formato DD-MM-AAAA')

        CantEquipos=int(input("Digita a cuantos equipos se les dará servicio: "))
        Cant = 0
        Cargo=[]
        while True:
            DescripcionServ = str(input("Digita la descripcion del servicio para este equipo: ")) #Descripcion por servicio del equipo
            DescripcionEq = str(input("Digita la descripcion del equipo: "))
            CargoEq = float(input("Digita el cargo para este equipo: $"))
            Lista.append(DescripcionServ)
            Lista.append(DescripcionEq)
            Lista.append(CargoEq)
            Cargo.append(CargoEq)
            Cant+=1
            if Cant == CantEquipos:


                break
        MontoCobrado = sum(Cargo)
        print(f"Subtotal: {str(MontoCobrado)}")
        Iva = MontoCobrado*0.16
        print(f"Iva: {str(Iva)}")
        MontoTotal = MontoCobrado+Iva
        Lista.append(MontoTotal)
        print(f"Monto total: {str(MontoTotal)}")
        Tupla=tuple(Lista)
        print(Tupla)
        Mi_TuplaN = TuplaN._make(Tupla)
        print(Mi_TuplaN)


    if Respuesta == 2:
        print("Gracias por su compra, buen día")
        with open("EV2.csv", "w", newline="") as Archivo:
            Grabador = csv.writer(Archivo)
            Grabador.writerow(("Clave", "Nombre", "Fecha", "Descripcion servicio", "Descripcion equipo", "Monto por Equipo", "Monto Total"))
            Grabador.writerows([(clave, Mi_TuplaN.Nombre, Mi_TuplaN.Fecha, Mi_TuplaN.DescripcionServicio, Mi_TuplaN.DescripcionEquipo, Mi_TuplaN.MontoPorEquipo, Mi_TuplaN.MontoTotal)
                                for clave in Diccionario.keys()])
        break
```

Me marca el error de "Expected 6 arguments, got 9" cuando le pongo que quiero servicio para mas de un equipo (entiendo que es devido a que cuando declare la tupla nominada solo puse 6 y luego con la descripción del servicio el equipo y el monto hacen 9) pero mi pregunta es como soluciono esto sin que tengo que manualmente incrementar en la declaración de la tupla a 9.

Pongo lo que me encargaron ya que creo que se puede hacer mas eficiente de otra manera pero me obliga mi maestro a que lo haga con tuplas nominadas.
Lo que trato de hacer es esto (es mi tarea):
Se deberá demostrar la aplicación de listas anidadas o diccionarios (En ambos casos con tuplas
nominadas)
Se debe ofrecer un menú navegable con las siguientes opciones:
3.1. Registrar un servicio (Debe incluir folio único, fecha del servicio, nombre del cliente y monto
cobrado)
3.1.1.Considere que en un solo servicio pueden atenderse uno o más equipos y para cada uno
de ellos se debe capturar el detalle consistente en:
3.1.1.1. Descripción del servicio para cada equipo
3.1.1.2. Descripción del equipo
3.1.1.3. Cargo generado por cada equipo atendido
3.1.1.4. Al final del registro de cada servicio:
3.1.1.4.1. Se debe informar el monto total a pagar por parte del cliente
3.1.1.4.2. Calcular e informar del IVA aplicable al servicio (16% del monto total de
la venta)
3.1.1.4.3. Almacenar de manera no volátil (archivo CSV) dicho servicio y su detalle
y ya no deberá volver a utilizarse para otro servicio el folio único
correspondiente.
3.1.1.5. Consultar un servicio (Esto se realizará mediante el folio correspondiente)
3.2. Consultar los servicios realizados en una fecha específica (Este reporte deberá ser tabular con el
desglose correspondiente del detalle de cada servicio según corresponda así como el costo de
cada detalle, el subtotal, el IVA aplicable y el gran total de cada servicio.
3.3. Consultar los datos de folio y nombre del cliente de los servicios atendidos en un rango de
fecha que el usuario indicará; este listado deberá ser tabular
3.4. Salir

Comment: Buen día, creo qué hay un error de concepto, las tuplas son inmutables. [Lectura recomendada](https://ellibrodepython.com/tuplas-python)

Answer (score 0):

*mi pregunta es como soluciono esto sin que tengo que manualmente incrementar en la declaración de la tupla a 9.*

Una vez declarada un namedtuple ya no se puede modificar su estructura (ni tampoco su contenido; las tuplas son inmutables).

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar la tupla con 9 campos, dejando que los últimos tomen su valor por default. Así solo tendrás que modificar una línea; los restantes usos de los namedtuples quedarán igual.

Para declarar los valores por defaults, usa el parámetro `defaults=[lista]` al momento de declarar la namedtuple:

```
Record = namedtuple("registro", "id duracion tipo", defaults = [None, None, 1])
```

luego podrás crear tuplas con número variable de campos:

```
record1 = Record("001", 27)     # Sin especificar tipo
record2 = Record("002", 28, 5)  # Especificando tipo
print(record1)
print(record2)
```

produce:

```
registro(id='001', duracion=27, tipo=1)
registro(id='002', duracion=28, tipo=5)

Process finished with exit code 0
```